# Why does //span[2] not select the second span in a document?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have the following html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>A <span>one</span></p>

<p>B <span>two</span></p>

<p>C <span>three</span></p>

<p>D <span>four</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Running the XPath `//span[1]` gets the first span. However `//span[2]` returns null:

```
 input: document.evaluate("//span[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
output: <span>​one​</span>​

 input: document.evaluate("//span[2]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
output: null
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `[2]` has higher precedence as the `//`. You should read your original xpath query as:

```
//(span[2])
```

This means, it looks everywhere in the document for the second span element of the same parent element.

If you write `(//span)[2]` instead, it will look for span elements everywhere, and then select the second span.

Comment: Properly speaking, there is no *precedence* involve (unless you are speaking about the grammar production for the parser...) because this abbreviated form would be expanded to: `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::span[position()=2]` and `fn:position()` acts against the axe (implicit `child` in this case). One can agree that `(//span)[2]` is a short expression... but `/descendant::span[2]` it's more clear and more open to optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Because `//span[1]` refers to the first span element of the span's parent.  There are actually 4 that meet this criteria (all 4). You only see one due to using `.singleNodeValue`

`//span[2]` is asking for spans that are the 2nd child of their parent.

Try it with this body to see

```
<body>
<p>A <span>one</span></p>
<p>B <span>two</span></p>
<p>C <span>three</span></p>
<p>D <span>four</span><span>five</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: As for the fix, this works in SQL Server XPath, not sure about JS XPath: `(//span[1])[2]`

Comment: Thanks very much. I've accepted Elian's answer as it is slightly clearer. The example is really useful though.