# XSL using index of node at any level

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<content>
 <p>para 1<an>test 1</an></p>
 <p>para 2<an>test 2</an></p>
 <p>para 3<an>test 3</an></p>
</content>
```

and I have the following expression in xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text>Count: </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/content//an)" />
 <xsl:text> Content: </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="/content//an[2]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Why does /content//an[1] returns "test 1" and /content//an[2] return ""? The count says that there are 3. I'm using libxslt.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and complete and easy solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does //span\[2\] not select the second span in a document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780559/why-does-span2-not-select-the-second-span-in-a-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is a FAQ**.

One must be careful when using the `//` abbreviation.

```
//SomeName[1]
```

means: select all `SomeName` elements in the document that are the first `SomeName` children of their parent. Often the selected nodes are more than one (or even all the nodes).

**The correct way to select only the $k-th `SomeName` element in the document is**:

```
(//SomeName)[$k]
```

**In your case, use**:

(/content//an)[2]

**Remember**: The `[]` operator has a higher precedence (binds stronger) than the `//` abbreviation.

Comment: @Flack: I wish this were possible :)